# is iii7 a dominant chord with scale degree 3?

Tags: functional-harmony

As a mediant chord the iii chord has scale degrees ^3 ^5 and ^7. If we add the 7th (^2) it will have all degrees of the scale the serve a dominant function. Can it be said then that iii7 is actually a dominant chord? ALready, the theory textbooks say that iii6 can readily serve as a dominant chord without the ^2 because the the 6th of the 63 chord is hardly enough to kill its dominant function. However this is when the iii is in inversion with the bass note being ^5. This is not what I am asking. If you break apart a V chord you have 3 scale degrees which all pull to the tonic. ^5 points to the tonic by harmonic descending 5th, while ^7 and ^2 are upper and lower neighbors to ^1 and are the melodic tones most active to ^1. With these 3 tones in the mediant 7 chord, even though the bass is ^3 does it invalidate the other 3 scale degrees that all move to the tonic or can the iii7 be said to have dominant function in root position as well?

Comment: Probably not, as a dominant chord will have a tritone between ^3 and ^7. As in G7 - B and F. With ^3 and ^2, it's P5.

Comment: @Tim  V is a dominant chord without the 7th of the chord

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the third triad dominant?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/why-is-the-third-triad-dominant)

Comment: @User1079505 My question is about the iii7 chod, not the plain triad. The mediant with a 7th adds the only other dominant degree to the chord. This is not discussed in the other question.

Comment: Yeah, but iii triad alone may play the function of a dominant. 5th of V, that is 7th of iii doesn't change much. If you are asking about what changes when you add 7th to iii, you may want to emphasize it more in the question.

Comment: @user1079505 scale degree 2^is upper neighbor to ^1 and is the strongest melodic motion to the tonic... How is that it does not change much?

Comment: I would say the ^7 is the strongest tension, not ^2. But I see your point, and I agree the edited question is no longer a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

To be a dominant chord, it needs to first be a major triad; with a seventh, it needs to me a major triad with a minor seventh.

If we assume you are in C major, the iii (E-G-B) is a minor triad.  With a seventh, it is a minor seventh (E-G-B-D).  Neither of these will sound like a dominant.

If you were to raise the G to a G-sharp it would sound like a dominant, but it would "point" towards A minor, the relative minor.  We would call it the V/vi.  This is a fairly common occurence.

If you were instead to lower the B to a B-flat, it would sound like a diminished triad.  This would lead us to F, and be called the iii0/IV.

EDIT: After @Todd Wilcox's comment of

> "Can you elaborate on why, in the key of C major, the iii7 chord doesn’t sound and function like G/E? Or perhaps G/E no longer functions as a dominant chord with the altered bass note?"

I don't know for sure, but this is where my brain goes.  In C major, the pitch B, or scale-degree 7, sounds very unstable.  It wants to resolve upwards to C.  But the interval of the perfect fifth has a stabilizing effect.  I think (and this is just a hunch; I don't know how I'd prove it) that the addition of E in the bass provides a sense of stability.  E sits a perfect fifth below B and gives it some context.  That doesn't mean that you *couldn't* us this chord in place of a dominant.  It just would never be as strong as a true dominant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why, in the key of C major, the iii7 chord doesn’t sound and function like G/E? Or perhaps G/E no longer functions as a dominant chord with the altered bass note?

Comment: To me; Em/G and Em7/G **do** sound dominant, Em root position, Em7 root position and G/E sound like tonic prolongation.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I can hear it that way, too.  It would also depend on how it was used.  If one of those chords like Em/G appeared exactly where we'd expect a half cadence, for instance, we'd hear dominant.

Comment: @ToddWilcox when is G/E not Em7?

Comment: @phoog THAT is a very goo question!

Comment: @phoog I feel like that’s another way to ask the question that this answer is trying to answer. If G/E and Em7 are always the same, does that mean Em7 is essentially a G chord? Conversely, what about Em/G? Is that always G6?

Comment: Let's not forget G13 in key C. That includes the E note, and is still considered, and sounds dominant - 'cos it still is.

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach the analysis is how the chord fits into the progression. In major keys `iii` often progress to `vi`, roots by descending fifth, working in the secondary/modal chords region. Of course the strong progression from `V` is to `I`. So, to make `Vadd6` clearer, move to `I`. If you want `iii6/5` clearer, move to `vi`.

[German theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(music)#German_functional_theory) does have a concept relating `iii` to either the tonic or dominant chords. *Dominantparallele* or *Relative of the dominant* seems to be the one your aiming for. But I don't understand that theory in any depth.

After re-reading the question I think something needs to be added about the specific inversion. When doing analysis I think the simplest explanation is often the best. Along those lines, if you have tones that are arranged to match up with a *root position* chord, it's probably better to analyze it as such, instead of an inverted chord.

`iii7` is root position. Analyzing it as a kind of `V` means you need some inversion, but in order for the tone in the bass (the `^3`) to be a tertian chord tone, it needs to be the *thirteenth*, or we need to elevate an *added* `add6` to chord tone status, and putting it in the bass is analogous to a seventh in the bass. Chords extended to the ninth and beyond, in common practice, are not inverted. Or, `Vadd6` with the sixth in the bass is like a `V4/2` third inversion.

Root position `iii7` is simpler than a supposed inverted thirteenth chord with the thirteenth in the bass, or a quasi third inversion chord.

If the tones were arranged as `iii6/5` or `Vadd6`, for example `GBDE` in `C` major, with `G` the dominant as supposed chord root, I think you have a better case for calling the chord a *dominant with added sixth* rather than a *first inversion minor seventh chord on the mediant.*